# How do I add/remove an active class every 3 seconds and run a loop Vue?

Tags: vue.js

How to add a class for a block every 3 seconds, and then remove it and add a class for another block, and do it cyclically. That is, you need to add an active class to the boxitem block every three seconds

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<template>
    <section class="map mb-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-item active">1</div>
                <div class="box-item">2</div>
                <div class="box-item">3</div>
                <div class="box-item">4</div>
                <div class="box-item">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        &-item {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            font-size: 42px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            &.active {
                &:nth-child(1) {
                    background: red;
                }
                &:nth-child(2) {
                    background: blue;
                }
                &:nth-child(3) {
                    background: green;
                }
                &:nth-child(4) {
                    background: yellowgreen;
                }
                &:nth-child(5) {
                    background: pink;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `v-for` to loop the `box-item` divs, then [bind the `active` class](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style#binding-html-classes) to a dynamic value that updates every 3 seconds.  The dynamic value can loop between values 1 through 5 with normal JavaScript [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function

```html
<template>
  <section class="map mb-page">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div
          v-for="i in loopLength"
          class="box-item"
          :class="{ active: isActive === i }"
        >
          {{ i }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

let isActive = ref(1)
const loopLength = 5

onMounted(() => {
  let count = 1
  setInterval(() => {
    isActive.value = (count++ % loopLength) + 1
  }, 3000)
})
</script>
```